# Two taxonomies with the same slug

Tags: custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules

There is a custom post type "real estate" with the slug "sale" and 2 taxonomies city and property type. It is necessary that taxes are displayed refer to the same slug, that is

```
site.com/sale/tax-1/tax-2 - (site.com/sale/california/apartment) - works
site.com/sale/tax-1 - (site.com/sale/california) - works
site.com/sale/tax-2 - (site.com/sale/apartment) - does not work, 404 error, because it expects a taxonomy term for the "city", and since there is no such city as "apartment", it means that it gets an error. (apartment - this is a taxonomy term for a property type)
```

I understand why it doesn't work like that, but that's how it needs to be. Because you need to display objects by "city" and by property type, both together and separately, that is, you need to

```
site.com/sale/california/apartment - thus [post type > tax - city > tax - property type]
site.com/sale/california - thus [post type > tax - city]
site.com/sale/apartment - thus [post type > tax - property type]

function register_realty_post_type() {
  $args = array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Ads',
      ),
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite'   => array(
        'slug'       => 'sale/%realty_city%/%realty_type%',
        'with_front' => true
      ),
      'public'             => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'show_ui'            => true,
      'has_archive'        => 'sale',
      'menu_position'      => 15,
      'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
  );
  flush_rewrite_rules();

  register_post_type('realty', $args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_realty_post_type' );

function register_realty_taxonomies() {
  $taxonomies = array();

  $taxonomies['realty_type'] = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite'      => array(
      'slug' => 'sale'
    ),
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Type realty',
    ),
    'show_admin_column' => true
  );

  $taxonomies['realty_city'] = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite'      => array(
      'slug' => 'sale'
    ),
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'City',
    ),
    'show_admin_column' => true
  );

  foreach( $taxonomies as $name => $args ) {
    register_taxonomy( $name, array( 'realty' ), $args );
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_realty_taxonomies' );

function filter_post_type_link_realty_type($link, $post) {
  if( $post->post_type != 'realty' ) {
    return $link;
  }

  if( $cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'realty_type') ) {
    $link = str_replace('%realty_type%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);
    return $link;
  }
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link_realty_type', 10, 2);

function filter_post_type_link_realty_city($link, $post) {
  if( $post->post_type != 'realty' ) {
    return $link;
  }

  if( $cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'realty_city') ) {
    $link = str_replace('%realty_city%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);
    return $link;
  }
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link_realty_city', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem through the filter request.

Since we have a problem precisely in the fact that 2 taxes refer to 1 and the same slug, I change the query parameters through the filter.

site.com/sale/barcelona - works
site.com/sale/villa - 404 error, bcz WP expects it to be a city taxonomy term, not a property type

And through the filter, I check if the property type has such a term, if so, I delete the taxonomy request by city **[realty_city]** and add it by property type **[realty_type]**. A change is taking place.

I do this for both the city **[realty_city]** taxonomy and the property type **[realty_type]**

```
// For realty_type
add_filter('request', 'request_filter_for_realty_type');
function request_filter_for_realty_type($query_vars) {
  if 
  ( isset($query_vars['realty_city']) 
    && !get_term_by('slug', $query_vars['realty_city'], 'realty_city') 
    && get_term_by('slug', $query_vars['realty_city'], 'realty_type') 
  ) 
  {
    $term = $query_vars['realty_city'];
    unset($query_vars['realty_city']);
    $query_vars['realty_type'] = $term;
  }
  return $query_vars;
}

// For realty_city
add_filter('request', 'request_filter_for_realty_city');
function request_filter_for_realty_city($query_vars) {
  if 
  ( isset($query_vars['realty_type']) 
    && !get_term_by('slug', $query_vars['realty_type'], 'realty_type') 
    && get_term_by('slug', $query_vars['realty_type'], 'realty_city') 
  ) 
  {
    $term = $query_vars['realty_type'];
    unset($query_vars['realty_type']);
    $query_vars['realty_city'] = $term;
  }
  return $query_vars;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is preventing two identical slugs to 2 different content.
How can he know where to send you if the URL may potentially be equal ?

I think you need to design your development differently. Having 1 term not hierarchical and then work on URL rewriting.
You could have only one "sale" and add it to a post with "california" or "apartment".